# how to find out buffer size C#

Tags: c#, udp, size, buffer

I need to send big file to another Computer with UDP Client help (C#). When i tryed send byte array I catchad Exception with text about buffersize. I think that I mist divide my big array on many little arrays and send it to another computer, but best of all I need to know my buffer size, then I can divide this normaly. I dint know what I must use. How can I know the buffersuze with C# help.
I am write big application which read some infro from form and convert it to byte array, after that it sends to another IP

```
string regInfo =
            "new" + "|" +
            GlobalInfo.profInf.UserName + "|" +
            GlobalInfo.profInf.MD5HS + "|" +
            GlobalInfo.profInf.E_mail + "|" +
            GlobalInfo.profInf.NickName + "|" +
            Encoding.UTF8.GetString(GlobalInfo.profInf.ProfileImage) + "|" +
            GlobalInfo.profInf.ShortInfo + "|";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(regInfo);
        GlobalInfo.sender.Send(buffer, buffer.Length);
```

Comment: Could you post the code that you have at the moment please?

Comment: i am write big application which read some infro from form and convert it to byte array, after that it sends to another IP